# How to add predefined users to a specific group in linux/bash script

Tags: shell

I have been trying to implement a code that makes a predefined user created, be put into a specific groups (first 5 in *MyMembers*, next 5 in *MyGroup*, and last 5 to *MyMinions*), but I always got lost in coding it.

So far this is my code in **creating predefined user**.

```
#!/bin/bash
#This script adds a user with a hidden password to your #system.

ans=yes
while [[ "$ans" = yes ]] ;
do

if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ];
then
    read -p "Enter username: " username
    read -s -p "Enter password: " password
    egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
    echo "$username already exists!"
    exit 1
else
    pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt ($ARGV[0], "password")' $password)
    useradd -m -p $pass $username
    [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo -e "\nUser has been added to your system!" || echo "\nFailed to add the user!"
fi
else
    echo "Only root may add a user to the system"
    exit 2
fi

echo -e "\nDo you still want to add more users?. \nType yes to continue adding. \nType yes or any key to exit"

read ans
done
exit
```

Comment: It not really clear what your Q is, but maybe you want to put all of this into a function, then use 3 differnt loops to call the function, making your MyMems, MyGrps, MyMins.(sorry about typo earlier)  Good luck.

Comment: Nevermind guys, I find my way through it ^_____^.

just a question, how do i make the "Enter group name:" come down with the read command because the output looks like this:

Enter Username: someusername
Enter Password: somepassword Enter Groupname:

Comment: What do you mean by _come down with_? (You cannot show in a comment how a multiline output looks; add that to the main question.)